# Connect to Ubuntu Share From Fedora 16

Tags: fedora, home-networking, ubuntu-10.10, home-server

I am having some trouble connecting to an Ubuntu 10.10 server.

I am using Fedora 16.

Some things that I have tried

- The server and all of its shares can be seen on the windows computer.
- I can ping the server and other window machines successfully
- I have installed samba and samba client on the fedora machine.
- Under Network on the fedora machine, I have one option "Windows
  Network"

  *After installing Samba and samba client I was able to enter.

  *I then am given a Work Group Icon
  *When Trying to connect to the work group I get the error message

  `Unable to mount location - Failed to retrieve share list from server`

Additional Notes/Updates

-The windows machine on the network also has a shared folder (Which cannot be seen)

From the research I have done already it seems that the only way to solve this is pretty complicated. I have been through a few tutorials, guides, etc but nothing has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to connect.

Earlier I had tried mounting via terminal after modifying /etc/fstab and was still unable to get that to work.

Finally I added the following line to /etc/fstab

```
//SERVER/SHARE /home/name/folder cifs user=USER,uid=1000,gid=100,noperm 0 0
```

To have it auto mount the directory some parameters needed to be specified and your password needed to be stored somewhere.

```
//SERVER/SHARE /home/name/folder cifs users,auto,credentials=/path/credentials_file,noexec,noperm 0 0
```

A file was then created with the directory = to credentials=/path/credentialsfile and these two lines were added to that file. Correct permissions etc were given by using the tutorial I link to later.

```
user=usernameofshare
password=sambapassword
```

Where:

```
SERVER = IP of Server
/home/name/folder = location to mount too
SHARE = the share name of the folder/file, not sure if using the real name when the sharename is different will work.
USER=my username
```

When I run `mount -a` the share mounts successfully.

This link has some nice examples of every type of connection

[FSTAB Modifications](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=283131)